# Solo una sesión activa por usuario en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, login, sesiones

¿Cómo podría limitar a que el usuario solo pueda tener una sesión iniciada en el sistema  a la vez? Estoy utilizando el sistema de autenticación que Laravel trae por defecto. En el caso que intente iniciar sesión por segunda vez debería cerrarsele la anterior.

Comment: guarda la session en una base de datos y ya.

Comment: Si es lo que había pensado, podrías desarrollar mas tu idea o pasarme alguna información relativa al tema de la mejor forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luego de haber investigado encontré para laravel 5.5 esta

## **Solucion**

**1.** Copiar la función `sendLoginResponse` del archivo:

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php

y pegarla en el archivo

> app/Htpp/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

Esto sobrescribirá la función predeterminada `sendLoginResponse`, (nunca debe realizar esto directamente en el archivo de la carpeta vendor, pues al realizar un composer update perderia sus cambios).

**2.** Actualizar su base de datos agregando en la tabla de usuarios un campo de tipo text llamado:

> session_id

.

**3**. Deje la función que copio en su LoginController `sendLoginResponse` de esta forma

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    $previous_session = Auth::User()->session_id;
    if ($previous_session) {
        \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
    }

    Auth::user()->session_id = \Session::getId();
    Auth::user()->save();
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}  

//No olvide colocar en el inicio del archivo: 
   // use Auth;
   // use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   // use Session;
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel ya tiene soporte para esto.

Por peticion repetire lo que dice claramente la documentacion.
Primero actualizar laravel a la ultima versión o a una versión posterior a la 5.6
Esto es muy simple solo tienes que actualizar el composer.json en la linea 13 por esto.

```
"laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
```

Despues en tu consola ejecutar el comando

```
composer updated
```

Una vez que actualice el proyecto deberás ir al kernel de los midelwares y descomentar esta linea.

```
'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class, "Esta"
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Una vez que la des comentaste tienes que agregar la siguiente linea con el fakade de auth (obviamente donde hagas el login o donde requieras que la sesión sea única por usuario).

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; // extensión del fakade

Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password);
```

Obviamente previo a esto tienes que tener disponible la contraseña del usuario. Un ejemplo bastante practico seria en el login normal de laravel.
En el constructor de login

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
     if(Auth::check()){
         Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->input('password'));
     }
}
```

Y así en cualquier otro caso de uso.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices

Comment: recuerda que solo responder con enlaces se considera de baja calidad; dale editar y añade una explicación y ejemplo del mismo