# Como recuperar las sesiones de los usuarios Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, sesiones

Hola estoy realizando una aplicación donde los usuarios solo pueden tener una sesión abierta, no importa en que dispositivo estén.

Ejemplo un usuario inicia sesión en un navegador web.
Después de 1 minutos decide cambiarse a su celular.

En este caso la sesión del navegador web se debe de caducar y ya no le debe de permitir hacer cambios.

Ahora mi problema es que cuando autentifico al usuario.

Lo primero que hago es preguntar si esta autentificado o tiene alguna sesión iniciada.

```
if(isset(Auth::user()->session) && Auth::user()->session != ''){
     Auth::logout();
     Session::getHandler()->destroy(Auth::user()->session);
}
```

Cabe mencionar que modifique la tabla de usuario agregando un campo donde guardo la sesión.

Una vez que verifique que no hubiera sesion y en caso de que la hubiera esta se haya eliminado. 
Procedo a crear las nuevas credenciales.

```
$user = (object) User::find($id)->toArray();
$user->status_session = Session::getId();
$user->save();
if (Auth::attempt(['email' =>  $user->email, 'password' => $user->password])) {
     return redirect('/home');
  }
```

El problema es que no elimina las sesiones de otros navegadores.

No es duplicado dado que no ocupa el mismo caso de uso de la pregunta por la cual fue postulada como duplicada. La respuestas que dan en esa pregunta es algo que estoy implementando. 
Guardo la sesión en base de datos la cual recupero con el facade de auth

```
Auth::user()->session
```

Elimino la sesión y vuelvo a iniciar una nueva sesión. 
Es lo mismo que tiene que responden en ese caso. Eso ya esta implementado. Ahora eso me lleva a lo siguiente.

No se porque en mi caso no funciona. Las sesiones siguen abiertas en diferentes lugares. Y la pregunta es pesifica es.

**¿Como recuperar la sesión o sesiones especificas del usuario creadas en el servidor?**

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Solo una sesión activa por usuario en Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148746/solo-una-sesi%c3%b3n-activa-por-usuario-en-laravel)

Comment: Haha lo curioso es que no utilizo ese método porque no estoy utilizando la autentifican por defecto de laravel. Pense que eso había sido muy explicito cuando compartí mis métodos de login. No utilizo la autentificación porque lo hago por medio de un token que mando al correo electrónico. Ademas para el caso no me funciono ´porque no puedo eliminar las sesiones otros dispositivos. Aun así a partir de laravel 5.6 integro autentificacion por protocolo http. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices

Comment: En lo personal creo que cerrar una sesión de uno u otro dispositivo no es bueno, muchas empresas grandes como Google o Facebook no cierran sesión de ningún dispositivo, lo mejor seria comunicarle el historial de sus sesiones lugares y dispositivos desde se conecto.

Comment: te paso es link en caso de que quieras de verdad hacerlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148746/solo-una-sesión-activa-por-usuario-en-laravel/149228

Comment: El motivo de tener una sesión solo por dispositivo son temas de seguridad. La información que se maneja dentro de la app que estamos desarrollando es sumamente sensible. Si esta app tuviera un caso de uso de solo entretenimiento en la cual no se manejara esta información no me afectaría porque las capaz de seguridad disminuirían.